# Trying to line six images using div

Tags: html, css, image, centering

I keep running into an issue when lining up six images (2 images per row with text between both rows). For some reason, I cannot align them in the center and I could really use some tips before I lose my sanity. I want them to stay like the image attached even if the screen changes, can someone help?
[screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0LHZ.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="wrapper">
    <title>HighItsKy</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">     


    <div class="backgroundcolor">
        <h1>Community</h1>
            <h2>One of the most remarkable things about my streaming experience is that I have grown a fantastic community and met some wonderful people;
            the "Kyngdom" is where we build each other up, share memes, play games, and talk. We love and only want the best for each other here!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="video-trailer">
            <h1>GALLERY</h1>
        <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart7.jpg" alt="Drawing of Ky wearing headphones and making a peace sign">
            </div>
            
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart5.jpg" alt="Digital drawing of Ky looking surprised">
            </div>

            <h2>Left Image- Done by @Samzx_x on Twitch <br> Right Image- Done by @Vivkins on Twitch</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart4.jpg" alt="Digital drawing of Ky as queen with Mama Ky">
            </div>
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart1.jpg" alt="Digital drawing of Ky holding Minecraft weapons with fall guys characters, a monster from Alien Isolation, and her stepping
                on a rocket league vehicle">
            </div>
            <h2>Both Images- Done by @This_Lettuce on Twitter</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart2.jpg" alt="Digital drawing of Ky driving a green tractor over train tracks while a train is in the distance">
            </div>
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
                <img src="fanart3.jpg" alt="Digital drawing of Ky with her viewers">
            </div>
            <h2>Left Image- Done by @This_Lettuce on Twitter <br> Right Image- Done by @Derpy_Pandaa on Twitch</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

        </div>
```

```
.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.backgroundcolor h1, .backgroundcolor hr{
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.backgroundcolor ul{
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.backgroundcolor a
{
    color: #987b74;
}

.video-trailer h1{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
}

.video-trailer a{
    color: #987b74;
}

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
    margin-top: 170px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.fanartrow::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;

}

.fanartrow{
    padding-left: 500px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.fanartrow h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 600px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    font-size: 125%;
}

.fanartcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fanartcolumn img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}





@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .tabs{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  h2{font-size: 100%;} 
  
   .title{
        font-size: 25%;
   }
   container {
   height: 180px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }
iframe{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
     margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.fanartcolumn img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

  
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container nav{
    width: 95%;
    height: 76px;
}   
.container nav ul li {font-size: 25px; width: fit-content; height: fit-content;}
 .container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{
     font-size: 20px; 
     
 }
 .container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
 main h2{
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}

iframe{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
     margin-left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-75%);
}


.fanartcolumn img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following changes I made under `/* additions */` CSS. I flexed your `#wrapper container` and gave it a flex direction. For demonstration purposes, I put in dummy images to reflect how your images should act. Then I added another div to nest the `<h2>` so that they will align under respective images. I noticed you have a lot of padding associated with the h2' in an attempt to probably align those, I would suggest editing those a bit until you get your desired result under the image. But this should get you going.

```css
.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.backgroundcolor h1, .backgroundcolor hr{
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

.backgroundcolor ul{
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}

.backgroundcolor a
{
    color: #987b74;
}

.video-trailer h1{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a{
    color: #987b74;
}
.video-trailer h2 a:hover{
    color: #FACABC;
}

.video-trailer a{
    color: #987b74;
}

.video-trailer{
    background-image: radial-gradient(#f8f8f8, #FACABC, #f8f8f8);
    margin-top: 170px;
}

/* Clear floats after image containers */
.fanartrow::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;

}

.fanartrow{
    padding-left: 500px;
    padding-right: 100px;
}

.fanartrow h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 600px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    font-size: 125%;
}

.fanartcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.fanartcolumn img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

/* additions */
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-desc {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .tabs{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  h2{font-size: 100%;} 
  
   .title{
        font-size: 25%;
   }
   container {
   height: 180px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }
iframe{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
     margin-left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.fanartcolumn img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .container nav{
    width: 95%;
    height: 76px;
}   
.container nav ul li {font-size: 25px; width: fit-content; height: fit-content;}
 .container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{
     font-size: 20px; 
     
 }
 .container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
 main h2{
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}

iframe{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
     margin-left: 50vw;
    transform: translate(-75%);
}


.fanartcolumn img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <title>HighItsKy</title>
      <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/redrock" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/primer" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <div class="backgroundcolor">
         <h1>Community</h1>
         <h2>One of the most remarkable things about my streaming experience is that I have grown a fantastic community and met some wonderful people;
            the "Kyngdom" is where we build each other up, share memes, play games, and talk. We love and only want the best for each other here!
         </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="video-trailer">
         <h1>GALLERY</h1>
         <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Drawing of Ky wearing headphones and making a peace sign">
            </div>
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Digital drawing of Ky looking surprised">
              <div class="img-desc"><h2>Left Image- Done by @Samzx_x on Twitch</h2><h2> Right Image- Done by @Vivkins on Twitch</h2></div>
            </div>

         </div>
         <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Digital drawing of Ky as queen with Mama Ky">
            </div>
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Digital drawing of Ky holding Minecraft weapons with fall guys characters, a monster from Alien Isolation, and her stepping
                  on a rocket league vehicle">
              <div class="img-desc"><h2>Both Images- Done by @This_Lettuce on Twitter</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            
         </div>
         <div class="fanartrow">
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Digital drawing of Ky driving a green tractor over train tracks while a train is in the distance">
            </div>
            <div class="fanartcolumn">
               <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="Digital drawing of Ky with her viewers">
                        <div class="img-desc"><h2>Left Image- Done by @This_Lettuce on Twitter</h2><h2>Right Image- Done by @Derpy_Pandaa on Twitch</h2>
            </div>
            </div>

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```